# VS2017 throws linker error when used with pybind11

Tags: pybind11

I am using the VS2017 to use the C++ functions inside the python and I am using python 3.7.2. I get the linker error during the compilation. My target extension is .pyd.
My source code is as below

```
class Pet {
public:
    Pet(const std::string &name) : name(name) { }
    void setName(const std::string &name_) { name = name_; }
    const std::string &getName() const { return name; }

    std::string name;
};


namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(pyBindLibrary, m) {
    py::class_<Pet>(m, "Pet")
        .def(py::init<const std::string &>())
        .def("setName", &Pet::setName)
        .def("getName", &Pet::getName);


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_PyThread_tss_create    cpybind C:\Users\pkumar\source\repos\ConsoleApplicationCPP\cpybind\Source.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_PyUnicode_AsEncodedString  cpybind C:\Users\pkumar\source\repos\ConsoleApplicationCPP\cpybind\Source.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_PyBaseObject_Type  cpybind C:\Users\pkumar\source\repos\ConsoleApplicationCPP\cpybind\Source.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_PyMem_Calloc   cpybind C:\Users\pkumar\source\repos\ConsoleApplicationCPP\cpybind\Source.obj   1   
....
```

Comment: I guess the crucial question is: how do you compile? How do you link Python?

Comment: From looking at the errors, it looks like you're not passing the correct linker flags for `Python`. But yeah, you should write down your entire workflow - e.g. choose one from the docs: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html